# How to prove convergence a.s implies convergence i.p.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I am wonder whether it is true that:

$$\Pr\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N A_i\right)>\Pr(A_i)$$

I know that :

1. $\Pr\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N A_i \right) \leq S_1 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \Pr(A_i)$
2. $\Pr\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N A_i\right)\geq S_1-S_2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \Pr(A_i) - \sum\limits_{1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq N} \Pr\left(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2} \right)$

If it is not true. How can I proceed this question in the picture?

[Question Picuture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXrAU.png)

Answer (score 0):

$A \subseteq B$ implies $P(A) \leq P(B)$. Since $A_i$ is contained in the union its probability is smaller.